# Exclude supported language by external dependency (aar)

Tags: android, gradle

How to exclude supported languages by an external dependency (.aar)? The external dependency is supporting more languages that my application, and I'm trying to avoid having activities with different languages according if it comes from the external dependency or not.

I've been trying something like this, but without success:

`compile ('...-3.17.1@aar') { exclude("res/values-es") }`

Comment: `exclude` is for transitive dependencies, not the contents of a single dependency. I would look into [resource shrinking](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#unused-alt-resources).

Comment: it's exactly what I'm looking for. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#unused-alt-resources

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        resConfigs "en", "fr"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `packagingOptions` available in gradle and exclude specific values folder from dependent aar file

https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html

You can follow above link for more details.